# Software name in a question's title: good or repetitive?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I couldn't find anyone asking this in here before, but there might be a similar question in other metas. And it might be a silly one, but here it goes:

If a title is too short, or too specific, should the name of the software (ex. illustrator question, inkscape, gimp) be in it? "Enlarge path", to name one. It has the tag underneath, but at first glance you can't figure out what soft it relates to, and I am in doubt about editing. Has this been agreed before (no soft on title)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to see the program's name in the question title. I've never used GIMP, Inkscape, or Fireworks, as examples, so there's little point in my reading those questions because I can't contribute anything.

I don't mind a little redundancy for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen this as a problem on this site. Some folks have a serious issue with it on the very high-traffic sites like SO, but it's not been something we've been worried by. Tagging correctly helps a question's discoverability in search, so is important.